# Вопросительные знаки: "Сколько ему лет? Девять? Десять?"

Tags: пунктуация, вопрос

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с пунктуацией. "Сколько ему лет? Девять? Десять?" Не много ли вопросительных знаков? Может, следует как-то иначе оформить, например: "Сколько ему лет: девять, десять?" Хотя двоеточие мне тоже кажется не вполне уместным. И будто интонация уже меняется. Подскажите, как правильно оформить текст. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Анна, у Вас нормально написано с самого начала. Почему Вы решили, что выходит ерунда? Вопросительные знаки ничем не мешают, хоть десяток поставьте.
Если вам надо передать какой-то акцент говорящего на каком-то слове, особенности речи или ситуации, то расскажите, что не нравится в исходном, что хотелось бы получить. А так Вы только путаете и себя и других. Отвечающие не знаю, что Вам здесь не угодило, поэтому могут только гадать.

Вариант Сержа с вопросительными внутри фразы, мне кажется, не совсем тут годится, поскольку не все члены однородны, поэтому после каждого вопроса - заглавная, как у Вас и было.

Comment: Просто количество вопросительных знаков мне кажется избыточным. И я хотела бы их сократить. Но я не знаю, как это сделать правильно, чтобы и смысл сохранился и ошибки допущены не были.

Answer (score 0):

Вы же сами все объяснили: интонация меняется. Вот какая вам нужна, такие знаки и ставьте.

Comment: Но, возможно, есть правило на этот счет. Я просто не смогла найти примеры. Просто у меня есть текст с вопросительными предложениями, но обилие "?" смущает. Я думала как-то сократить знаки вопроса: "Сколько ему лет? Девять? Десять? Откуда он приехал? Я видела его здесь впервые".

Answer (score 0):

Можно оформить и так: **Сколько ему лет -  девять, десять? Сколько ему лет -  девять? десять?** 
Но ваш вариант тоже верный.

Вопросительный знак может ставиться в вопросительном предложении после каждого однородного члена с целью расчленения вопроса: Что я — попугай? индейка? (М.);

См.: Справочник по пунктуации. Розенталь, Д.Э.

Comment: Спасибо! А если оформить так: **"Сколько ему лет - девять, десять? Откуда он приехал? - я не знаю, я видела его здесь впервые"**. Или **"Сколько ему лет - девять, десять? Откуда он приехал?.. Я не знаю - я видела его впервые"**. Или вообще какая-то ерунда выходит. Уже запуталась. Как стоит оформить, на ваш взгляд.

Comment: Можно так: Откуда он приехал? Я не знаю - я видела его впервые. Или, если это косвенный вопрос, так: Откуда он приехал(— ,)я не знаю. Знаки в скобках факультативны. .

Comment: Спасибо за совет. В скобках у вас (— ,), но разве не наоборот ставится. В смысле, сначала запятая, а потом уже тире? (,—)

Comment: Вы не поняли: речь идет о факультативности знаков, т. е. на выбор - или тире или запятая.

Comment: А, все, поняла. Простите, я подумала вы предлагаете вариант: "Откуда он приехал, — я не знаю". Извините, не так поняла.